# Is it possible to calculate interval from percentage in a normal distribution without software?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a problem like this:

> In a car factory a study was made to calculate how long each worker
>   takes to build a part. The mean  μ = 75 seconds  and the standard
>   deviation  σ = 6 seconds.
>
> Find an interval in which the probability of a worker building a part
>   in t seconds, t belonging to that interval, is 80%.

I can calculate this using my calculator (I think that is the point of that problem), but I would like to know if it is possible to do this manually, if there is some formula or anything for this and if yes, how.

Thanks

Comment: I would say manually using the tables of the normal distribution.

Comment: @georg That did the trick, thanks. I didn't know such tables existed.